# Let $R$ be a PID and $a,x\in R$. Show that $x\left(R/Ra\right)=(Rx+Ra)/Ra$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a PID and $a,x\in R$. Show that $x\left(R/Ra\right)=(Rx+Ra)/Ra$. (where $Ra$ and $Rx$ denotes the ideals, generated by $a$ and $x$ respectively.

What I did was to show that the sets on both sides coincide. Let $xr+Ra\in x\left(R/Ra\right).$ Then $xr+Ra=xr+a+Ra\in (Rx+Ra)/Ra$. Conversely, let $r_1x+r_2a+Ra\in (Rx+Ra)/Ra$. Then $r_1x+r_2a+Ra=r_1x+Ra\in x(R/Ra)$.

Is that correct? I don't think that $R$ being a PID is neccessary. Also, is there a more elegant way to do it? Maybe by the second isomorphism theorem?